# ggplot in R: barchart with log scale label misplacement

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

So I have a bar chart to make, and a log plot for y axis is warranted because of the data range.  So the problem is I have the value of 0.5, which in log10 is -0.3.
Since the bar goes into negative, the "top" of the bar, which is used for placing the labels is actually the "bottom" and so my text label is "just above" the bottom, which means in the middle of the bar.
I figure I am probably not the first person with this issue, but searching for related fixes has not helped.  Most notably, I tried using dodge, but this does not change that the "top" of the bar is really the "bottom".

So two questions:

1. Can I fix this label mishap?
2. This is just ugly: can I move the x axis up to y=1 to give more context to the negative value without moving the x axis labels?

.

```
alpha=c('A','B','C','D')
value=c(0.5,10,40,1100)
table<-as.data.frame(alpha)
table<-cbind(table, value)
library(ggplot2) 
graph <- ggplot(table, aes(x=alpha)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(y=value),width=0.5) + 
  geom_text(aes(y=value,label=value),vjust=-0.5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans="log10",limits=c(0.5,1400))
graph + theme_classic()
```

[image: graph with labels incorrect]

Comment: As for number 2, just add an `geom_hline()` to draw the y = 0 line, and modify `theme_classic()` so the x-axis line isn't drawn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little trick modifying the `y` coordinate of the data labels (use `ifelse()` to set the value of `y` to `1` if the value is less than one). As for the axis, simply hide the X axis (setting it to `element_blank()`) and draw a new horizontal line:

```
graph <- ggplot(table, aes(x=alpha)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(y=value),width=0.5) + 
  # Modify the placing of the label using 'ifelse()':
  geom_text(aes(y=ifelse(value < 1, 1, value),label=value),vjust=-0.5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans="log10",limits=c(0.5,1400)) + 
  theme_classic() +
  # Hide the X axis:
  theme(axis.line.x = element_blank()) +
  # Draw the new axis
  geom_hline()
print(graph)
```

The output:

[image: Output for code above]

Comment: I've got a thing about if else.    aes(y=c(value[1]+0.6,value[-1]),label=value) works too.

Comment: I think you may want `element_blank()`

Comment: @JasonAizkalns Indeed! Thank you. Correcting right now

Comment: This is great.  I did not realize I could feed different data to the geom_text -- it seems so obvious now :D

Comment: @BAMF4bacon you can also hide the ticks of the X axis if you want (inside the `theme` function: `axis.ticks.x=element_blank()`)

Comment: @BAMF4bacon by the way, if you think this answer completely solves your issue, accept it ;)

Comment: Good tip.  Sorry about that -- I thought I had already accepted it.